# Reporting services using assembly function with optional parameters

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a ReportingServices report with an optional integer parameter. The parameter is nullable.
Report uses an Assembly for localization and formatting of strings in textboxes. The assembly has several overload for different parameter types (strings, booleans, etc)
The problem comes when the parameter takes NULL value, and this value is passed to a method of the assembly. I tried several options:

```
c# method: public static string Method1(string Name, int value, string CultureName)
expression: AssemblyName.Class1.Method1('SOMESTRING',Parameters!Param1.value, 'en')

c# method: public static string Method1(string Name, string CultureName, int? value)
c# method: public static string Method1(string Name, string CultureName, int? value = null)
expression: AssemblyName.Class1.Method1('SOMESTRING','en', Parameters!Param1.value)
```

And also:

```
public static string Method1(string Name, object objectInstance, string CultureName)
public static string Method1(string Name, string CultureName, object objectInstance = null)
```

This methods work ok when the parameter value is other than NULL, but when it's NULL, none of those seem to work: Expression returns "#ERROR" and there's a message indicating that an appropiate overload could not be found.

How should be the method declared so it is used when called with a nullable parameter valued "null"?

Thanks in advance.